# PHP ActiveRecord - использование нескольких БД

Tags: php

Всем привет! Кто-нибудь использовал фреймворк ActiveRecord в своих проектах? Меня интересует, как сделать, чтобы некоторые модели использовали одно подключение к БД, а другие - другое. Средствами фреймворка.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: это извращение сударь.

Уж лучше тогда делать выгрузки с одного сайта на другой, нежели на одном ресурсе иметь 2 подключения к 2м разным БД. Ломанут один сайт ломанут и остальные/

Comment: @Shrek, у меня было подобное извращение, надо было магазин прикрутить к 64-гиговой базе, там приходилось иметь 2 подключения, так что проблема имеет место быть. Но это оффтоп, я на голых `mysql_*` делал.

Comment: Oo жестокие вы люди.

Comment: Да ситуация такая, есть отдельный сайт со своей базой. Но там есть раздел где надо брать инфу и с другой базы, просто переносить не вариант т.к та, 2 база ежедневно обновляется, и переносить придётся огромное кол-во данных, к тому же данные нужны в режиме онлайн, а не с задержкой(пока перенесётся с 1 на 2)
Поэтому вот и приходится так изворачиваться :(

Comment: Определитесь сначала с терминами ;)  ActiveRecord это шаблон проэктирования (pattern)

Comment: Ответить я на свой вопрос не могу, но решение нашел:
При установке подключения, можно задать еще одно с определенным именем.
$cfg->set_connections(array(
        'connection_name1' => 'mysql://' . DB_USER . ':' . DB_PASSWORD . '@' . DB_HOST . '/' . DB_NAME . '?charset=' . DB_CHARSET,
        'connection_name2' => 'mysql://' . DB_USER2 . ':' . DB_PASSWORD2 . '@' . DB_HOST2 . '/' . DB_NAME2 . '?charset=' . DB_CHARSET,
      ));

А в самой модели делаем переменную
public static $connection = "connection_name2";

всё! :)